# Validar si existe registro en la base de datos con PDO

Tags: php, mysql, web

He intentado realizar una comprobación en la base de datos para verificar si un usuario existe o no. Para tal fin he dispuesto el siguiente código:

```php
$query = $bd->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE area_usuario = $area_res AND cita_usuario = $cita_res");
$query->execute();
$existencia = $query->fetchColumn();
if($existencia > 0){
    print("1");
}else{
    print("0");
}
```

Sin embargo, al realizarse la comprobación, no me sale el 1 cuando un usuario está registrado sino que todo lo valida como 0 (*como si no existiera a pesar de que está en la base de datos*). Cómo se podría proceder para realizar la validación y me muestre el 1.

Comment: Hola Elisa, no veo errores en tu código. ¿Probaste imprimir la consulta, copiarla y ejecutarla en MySQL a ver que devuelve?

Comment: He probado el código en mi ambiente y no tiene fallas.

Answer (score 0):

Generalmente son problemas de sentencia SQL que no se arman correctamente.

Como te dijo Marcos anteriormente podes imprimir la consulta en pantalla para ver si se arma correctamente y llevarla a phpmyadmin o al cliente de MySQL que manejes y probarla directamente en MySQL en la ventana consultas.

Entonces tu código puedes hacerlo así.

```
  //crear la consulta
  $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE area_usuario = $area_res AND 
      cita_usuario = $cita_res";

  // imprimir la consulta en pantalla
  echo $sql;

  //mato el proceso para que no continue
  die();
```

Ahora esa consulta se ve en pantalla y puedes copiarla y pegarla en el cliente de mysql y ver si la consulta funciona bien

Aqui tenemos 2 (dos ) posibilidades

1. que la consulta no funcione porque falta algo- comillas generalmente - o que las variables no tengan el valor deseado.

   En este caso solo queda arreglar la Consulta.
2. que la consulta funcione bien en la consola

   En este caso te sugiero que armes la consulta antes del prepare(),  y no utilices prepara() y execute().

   Utiliza en su lugar query()

   Eso quedaría así

   ```
        $sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE area_usuario = $area_res AND cita_usuario = $cita_res";

        // Ö

        $sql= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM usuario WHERE area_usuario = ".$area_res." AND cita_usuario = ".$cita_res;

        // y despues

        $consulta=$bd->query($sql);

        $existencia = $consulta->fetchColumn();
   ```

Algunas veces he tenido problemas con prepara() y las variables que se reemplazan
y pude solucionarlas de esa manera

Espero te ayude
Saludos